# SQL check for records that have specific features in child entities (1 to n)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following structure in my Oracle database:

account --> 1 to n --> cards --> 1 to 1/0 --> members

Now I want to find out how many accounts there are, that have at least 1 member that is no child of the main card AND the main card has no member.
'Card' has an attribute type, that can be 'main' or 'other'.

I would like to find entries with this structure. Note that the member is the child of the card that is not of type 'main' and the card with type 'main' has no children:

```
**Account**:
id:1

**Cards**:
id:1
type:main
account_id: 1
______
id:2
type:other
account_id: 1

**Members**:
id:1
card_id:2
```

Comment: Sorry, it's an Oracle database. I edited the question as well.

Comment: It might be helpful to add sample data and expected results.

Comment: So `main` is an attribute of `card`?

Comment: Right, 'card' can be of different 'types', including 'main'

Comment: @AlexPoole done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from Accounts a
where id in
(
select account_Id 
from Cards c
where "type"='main' and
     not exists (select * from members m 
                 where m.card_id = c.id)
) and id in
(
select account_Id 
from Cards c
where "type"='other' and
     exists (select * from members m 
                 where m.card_id = c.id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional `count` in `having` clause:

```
select a.id
    from account a
    left join cards c on c.account_id = a.id
    left join members m on m.card_id = c.id
    group by a.id
    having count(case when c.type = 'main' and m.id is null then 1 end) >= 1
       and count(case when c.type = 'other' then m.id end) >= 1
```

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/BAUA85641)</sup>**